# Why can the author reassign a new object to a val via update?

Tags: kotlin

The Code A is from offical sample code [here](https://github.com/android/compose-samples/blob/main/JetNews/app/src/main/java/com/example/jetnews/ui/interests/InterestsViewModel.kt).

The  `private val _uiState` is `val`, in my mind, a val can be only assigned a object for one time.

It seems that `_uiState.update { it.copy(loading = true) }` shows `_uiState` is assigned to a new object again by `update`.

I don't understand why the author can reassign a new object to a val via `update`, could you tell me?

**Code A**

```
data class InterestsUiState(
    val topics: List<InterestSection> = emptyList(),
    val people: List<String> = emptyList(),
    val publications: List<String> = emptyList(),
    val loading: Boolean = false,
)

class InterestsViewModel(
    private val interestsRepository: InterestsRepository
) : ViewModel() {

    // UI state exposed to the UI
    private val _uiState = MutableStateFlow(InterestsUiState(loading = true))
    val uiState: StateFlow<InterestsUiState> = _uiState.asStateFlow()


    private fun refreshAll() {
        _uiState.update { it.copy(loading = true) }
         ...
    }

    ...
}   

data class InterestsUiState(
    val topics: List<InterestSection> = emptyList(),
    val people: List<String> = emptyList(),
    val publications: List<String> = emptyList(),
    val loading: Boolean = false,
)  

/**
 * Updates the [MutableStateFlow.value] atomically using the specified [function] of its value.
 *
 * [function] may be evaluated multiple times, if [value] is being concurrently updated.
 */
public inline fun <T> MutableStateFlow<T>.update(function: (T) -> T) {
    while (true) {
        val prevValue = value
        val nextValue = function(prevValue)
        if (compareAndSet(prevValue, nextValue)) {
            return
        }
    }
}
```

**Added Content**

To Chaoz: Thanks!

But all members in `data class InterestsUiState(...val loading: Boolean = false）`is val type, and you can't change any member vaule when you have created the object of `InterestsUiState`.

So I can't still understand why the member value of `_uiState` can be changed when the author launch  `_uiState.update { it.copy(loading = true) }`.

**And more**

`_uiState.update { it.copy(loading = true) }` is equal to
`_uiState.value = _uiState.value.copy(loading = true)`, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `val` keyword only refers to which object the variable holds, not the data inside said object. For example:

```
class MyClass(var value: Int)
```

The following code is *not* allowed:

```
val obj = MyClass(5)
obj = MyClass(7) // compile error
```

because the `val` keyword refers to the variable itself being reassigned to a different object. This code, however, *is* allowed:

```
val obj = MyClass(5)
obj.value = 7
```

Here, obj is still the same object, only a property of said object changed value. In your provided code, the update function modifies data stored inside the `_uiState` object, however it does not swap it for a new object. This is important because:

```
var obj = MyClass(5)
val copy = obj
obj = MyClass(7)
println(copy.value) // prints 5
println(obj.value)  // prints 7
```

When reassigning a variable, the old object remains, and any other variables referencing that object are not updated. In your case, `_uiState.value` is modified, not the variable itself. Hope this clears things up!

**Edit:**

Yes, `it.copy()` is an expression which creates a new object. However, this code is executed in the line `_uiState.update { it.copy(loading = true) }`, in the `refreshAll()` function. As it is the last statement in a lambda expression (also the only one, but doesn't matter), it is the return value of said lambda. Here we have to look at the declaration of the update function.
The lambda is stored in the `function` variable (of type `(T)->T`). This means, whenever `function()` is called, the code inside the lambda is executed, and its result (a new object) is then returned by the `function()` call. This value is assigned to the `val nextValue` variable and not to `_uiState` itself. The `compareAndSet` function modifies `_uiState.value` and does not change the object the `_uiState` variable references.
And by the way, the object returned by `it.copy()` is of type T, and not of type `MutableStateFlow<T>`, which your `_uiState` variable holds. T is the type of `_uiState.value`.

Comment: Thanks! but `it.copy(loading = true) ` will return a new object

Comment: And that new object is the return value of the lambda, not a new object assigned to the property `_uiState`.

Comment: @HelloCW updated answer regarding your comment

Comment: Thanks! Would you please to see my added content in the question?